Limit symbol in different font
I am using the following for a beamer presentation (the beamer presentation is using a custom font as the main and sans font so have manually set a different maths font as shown below)
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular}
But this prints the limit sign in the traditional latex maths font (neither the main, sans or math font).
Is there an easy fix for this?

Please always include a small, but compilable test document in your questions.

Please add in your example which sans and main font you are using.

Please add a compilable test document to your question. If you can't share your custom font, use some other freely available font. If I try to reproduce your problem, simply changing the main font will also change the font used for lim

Change the main font and it will change the font for lim as well:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    Ordinary text.
    \[ x \lim\limits_{min} \]
  \end{frame}

\end{document}


(alternatively, unicode-math offers the \setoperatorfont macro to change the operator font)
